# How to display iphone version,IOS version,name of the the Network Provider in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am developing an iPhone app. In its about page I want to display the iPhone version, iOS version, and the name of the the Network Provider. I want fetch these from the phone itself. How would I do that? Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model Version:

```
NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

iOS Version:

```
NSString *systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```

Carrier name (iOS 4.0 minimum):

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>

CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *carrierName = [carrier carrierName];
[netInfo release];
```